# Autocorrelation: Error Message 'lag.max' must be at least 0, even though I set a lag.max

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I have a error in R, which I cant repair.

I have a nested dataframe "dfNEST" with ID's and the data from each person.

In the data I have the column "steps", which have some NA's. Thats why I use na.action = na.exclude.

```
map(dfNEST$data,~acf(.$steps, lag.max = 30, na.action = na.exclude))
```

When I run this code, I get the message "'lag.max' must be at least 0, even though I set the max to = 30. How can I get this code to run?

Comment: Did you try to use `na.omit` for `.$steps` ?

Comment: @TaherA.Ghaleb shouldnt na.action = na.exclude do the same?

Comment: You mean you tried it and got the same error? `na.omit(.$steps)`

Comment: @TaherA.Ghaleb so you mean inside the acf-function? It gives me the error "'ts' object must have one or more observations"